# Thymeleafのth属性はなぜHTMLが無視できるようになっているのでしょうか？HTMLのどの仕様でしょうか？

Tags: html, thymeleaf

[Tutorial: Using Thymeleaf (ja)](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf_ja.html)

下記引用にHTMLが（ブラウザが？）無視してくれるという記述があります。

引用:

> スタンダードダイアレクトの大半のプロセッサは「属性プロセッサ」です。属性プロセッサを使用すると、XHTML/HTML5テンプレートファイルは処理前であってもブラウザで正しく表示することができます。単純にその属性が無視されるからです。例えば、タグライブラリを使用したJSPだとブラウザで直接表示できない場合がありますが:
> `<form:inputText name="userName" value="${user.name}" />`
> Thymeleafスタンダードダイアレクトでは同様の機能をこのように実現します:
> `<input type="text" name="userName" value="James Carrot" th:value="${user.name}" />`
> ブラウザで正しく表示できるだけでなく、(任意ですが)value属性を指定することもできます(この場合の “James Carrot” の部分です)。プロトタイプを静的にブラウザで開いた場合にはこの値が表示され、Thymeleafでテンプレートを処理した場合には ${user.name} の評価結果値で置き換えられます。

属性にコロンを使った `th:value` の書き方は見慣れないのですが、HTMLのどういった仕様がこれを無視してくれるのでしょうか？

Comment: 英語版SOに[同様の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15038049/4506703)がありました。こちらではHTML4.01のspecへのリンクがあります。

Comment: HTML4.01では無視する挙動が望ましいとされているという感じでしょうか。

Comment: HTML4.01では無視すべし(と明記されているのでvalid)、HTML5ではそのような記述はないのでinvalid(ただし互換性を考えると、warning的なものは発するかもしれないが、無視する他ないのでは)、ということかな、と。

Comment: HTML5的にvalidにするためにカスタムデータ属性使って設定できるようにしよう、[みたいなissue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/93)もありました。試していませんが実装されているように見えるので、`data-th-value`も使えるのかも？

Comment: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html にも言及がありますので、使えそうですね。

Answer (score -1):

Spring BootとThymeleafの組み合わせで実現されているもので、HTMLの仕様によるものではありません。

[4.1. テンプレートエンジン(Thymeleaf)](https://macchinetta.github.io/server-guideline-thymeleaf/current/ja/ArchitectureInDetail/WebApplicationDetail/Thymeleaf.html#id7)　の記事をじっくりと読まれることをお勧めします。

記事の4.1.1.3節で図示されているように、リクエストを受けてから、レスポンスを返すまでに、様々な処理が行われるのです。

Comment: XHTML/HTML5テンプレートファイルは「処理前」であってもブラウザで正しく表示することができます。 とあるので、組み合わせは、関係ないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 質問文の引用箇所は、ThymleafのテンプレートはHTMLとしても(=テンプレートエンジンを介さなくても)妥当に見えるよ、という説明かと。JSPとかと違ってフレームワーク上でなくとも見た目のチェックができて便利だよね、みたいなことを説明しているのだと思います。